# Wifi doesn't work on my Lenovo G50-80(Ubuntu 17.10.1)

Tags: networking, wireless, laptop, lenovo, hardware

Wifi doesn't work on my Lenovo G50-80(Ubuntu 17.10.1). When I bought it was on windows os then I changed os to ubuntu and wifi doesn't work so I use a wired connection(LAN). Wifi didn't work with other Linux systems too. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what "doesn't work" means. Does it not connect ? Does it not list networks ? Does it not turn on ? Does it turn on but fail to obtain an IP ? Anyway, first thing to check is that the wifi adapter is operational or if it is missing a firmware file ("driver" in windows speak). Can you open a terminal and type "dmesg" (without the quotes). The output will be a bit of a beast, but have a scroll through and see if you have any messages relating to missing firmware and/or inability to start your wifi adapter.

Comment: [    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x20 (or later)

Comment: [    1.229783] DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \_SB.PCI0.SDMA
[    1.229788] DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \_SB.PCI0.SDHC

Comment: [   12.288042] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout   
////is that it?

Comment: No, that last one is for bluetooth. Nothing there seems to relate to wifi. A few other things to check. Is your wifi enabled in your BIOS ? Also, type "lspci -v" in a terminal, is your wifi card listed ? If it is, it should also list what "driver" it is using.

Comment: Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
 I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
 Memory at c0604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Memory at c0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
 Kernel modules: r8169

Comment: Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
 Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 10
 Memory at c0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>

Comment: The "access denied"  message is because you are not root. You can run the command again with "sudo lspci  -v". So your wifi adapter is a Broadcom BCM43142. Let me do a quick google on firmware....... hang on.

Comment: Ethernet controller:Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
 Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
 Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
 Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
 Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
 Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates

Comment: Network controller:Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
 Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
 Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-e2-ff-ff-ef-d8-5d
 Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    ///thanks

Comment: "https://askubuntu.com/questions/765584/is-it-possible-to-use-broadcom-bcm43142-wifi-in-ubuntu-16-04"   That link suggest turning off "secure boot" in the BIOS. If that doesn't work, it suggests using the "wl" driver, and gives details on how to install it. (sudo apt update && sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source). So, can you turn off "secure boot" in your BIOS and try again ?

Comment: have you solved the problem ? Can you tell me what you did so I can put the solution for others to see ?

Comment: Yes, sure. There is no Secure Boot in my BIOS, so I run the sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source commands in a terminal.

Comment: And now it is working ?

Comment: Yes, now it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was taken from this post.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/765584/is-it-possible-to-use-broadcom-bcm43142-wifi-in-ubuntu-16-04%22

The solution was to install the bcmwl package.

```
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```