# WiFi is not available after rebooting in Ubuntu-16.04.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

My WiFi was working perfectly in Ubuntu 16.04.4. I rebooted my laptop and after logging in, nm-applet did not show any WiFi AP. WiFi modem is up and running. But My nm-applet did not show anything.

- I have tried downgrading my kernel and reinstalling the Broadcom drivers but it did not work.
- I have tried to insall the older version of the broadcom driver but it also gave me the same error 
  `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error`
- My WiFi works when I use it from live pendrive.
- I have tried the steps in these

  - [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
  - [BCM4352 wireless driver issue modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2302133)
  - [Is it possible to use Broadcom BCM43142 wifi in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765584/is-it-possible-to-use-broadcom-bcm43142-wifi-in-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But even then my WiFi is not working.

`$ iwconfig` gives

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

My Kernel version: 4.4.0-116-generic

---

`$ls /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/updates/dkms/` gives

```
wl.ko
```

---

`$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` gives

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: NAMI
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 3
    Region 0: Memory at f0c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

---

`$ lshw -C network` spits

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f0c00000-f0c07fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 07
   serial: fc:3f:db:d5:e7:d7
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:32 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0b00000-f0b00fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

---

`$ sudo apt --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n libqt4-opengl linux-headers-4.4.0-119
  octave-info thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 51.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 374783 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2) over (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-116-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-116-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.1+13-0ubuntu2) ...
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
```

---

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386370

Comment: Yeah, I tried to install an old kernel in 4.4.0-112 on my pc. I downloaded it and I booted with the 4.4.0-112 kernel, but now I cannot even access my ethernet.  Am I missing out something here?

Comment: Is the module loaded? `lsmod | grep r816` Does it show up in `ifconfig`?

Comment: No my ethernet interface is not showing up in `ifconfig` in  the old kernel. `lsmod | grep r816` gives nothing.

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r816`  ?

Comment: `sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r816` gave `modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in the directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-112-generic`

Comment: Let's dig deeper. Please run and post: `sudo updatedb && locate r816 | grep .ko`

Comment: `sudo updated && locate r816 | grep .ko` gives `/lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/net/Ethernet/realtek/r8169.ko`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from  [this post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1030325/nvidia-driver-installation-v387-26-on-ubuntu-16-04/). As mentioned in the post this is just a workaround not a solution for the problem. According to the post, there is a bug in loading the **retpoline** module magic. So what we do here is just load it no matter RETPOLINE Is available or not. This fixed the issue for me. Thank you [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555), for your assistance.

`vim /usr/src/linux-headers-*/include/linux/vermagic.h`

**STEP 1** : Find the `#ifdef RETPOLINE`
and comment it ( `\\#ifdef RETPOLINE` ) 
and add a line `#if 1` below the commented line. The final file shoule look like the one given below and save the file.

```
#include <generated/utsrelease.h>

/* Simply sanity version stamp for modules. */
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_SMP "SMP "
#else
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_SMP ""
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_PREEMPT "preempt "
#else
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_PREEMPT ""
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_MODULE_UNLOAD "mod_unload "
#else
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_MODULE_UNLOAD ""
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_MODVERSIONS
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_MODVERSIONS "modversions "
#else
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_MODVERSIONS ""
#endif
#ifndef MODULE_ARCH_VERMAGIC
#define MODULE_ARCH_VERMAGIC ""
#endif
//#ifdef RETPOLINE
#if 1
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_RETPOLINE "retpoline "
#else
#define MODULE_VERMAGIC_RETPOLINE ""
#endif

#define VERMAGIC_STRING                     \
    UTS_RELEASE " "                         \
    MODULE_VERMAGIC_SMP MODULE_VERMAGIC_PREEMPT                 \
    MODULE_VERMAGIC_MODULE_UNLOAD MODULE_VERMAGIC_MODVERSIONS             \
    MODULE_ARCH_VERMAGIC                    \
    MODULE_VERMAGIC_RETPOLINE
```

**STEP 2**: Now reconfigure the bcmwl-kernel-source package `sudo dpkg-reconfigure bcmwl-kernel-source`.

**STEP 3**: Now restart the network manager `sudo service network-manager restart`. 
**STEP 4**: Enjoy your WiFi :)